# MySQL temp table issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, temp-tables

I'm trying to use temp tables to speed up my MySQL 4.1.22-standard database and what seems like a simple operation is causing me all kinds of issues.
My code is below....

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nonDerivativeTransaction_temp (
   accession_number varchar(30), 
   transactionDateValue date)
) TYPE=HEAP;

INSERT INTO nonDerivativeTransaction_temp 
VALUES( SELECT accession_number, transactionDateValue 
          FROM nonDerivativeTransaction 
         WHERE transactionDateValue = "2010-06-15");

SELECT * 
  FROM nonDerivativeTransaction_temp;
```

The original table (nonDerivativeTransaction) has two fields, accession_number (varchar(30)) and transactionDateValue (date).

Apparently I am getting an issue with the first two statements but I can't seem to nail down what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Insufficient information for meaningful answer, please elaborate a) What error  message you're getting b) What you expect to happen c) Schema of all tables mentioned d) Explain plan of all queries mentioned.

Comment: First off, please list the error you're getting (You say you're getting an issue with the first 2 statements, what issue exactly).  Secondly, what version of MySQL (There were a lot of versions of 4).  Third, you probably should upgrade to at least 5.0 (preferably 5.1) seeing as support for 4.x ended in either 2008 or 2009 depending on the version...

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `VALUES(`  in `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ( SELECT`, it's either VALUES() or SELECT, not both.

And normally this setup of yours would slow down things rather then speed them up unless you're querying the temporary table a LOT during the session, and query-caching is off and/or not feasible.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken. The original table has a TON of entries and I only need a given date at any particular time. My solution was to use a temp table to hold only those values of that particular date.

Comment: +1: It's a syntax error.  @AmyD: When in doubt, have a look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

A quick look makes me wonder if the mismatched parens might be part of your problem...

Comment: Holy crap! I can't believe I boned this on a such a simple mistake as a parens.